# How Can I reach EF Flattened Column in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Hello Everyone I have a problem to reach Flattened column in LINQ.
Here is my Auditable Entity

```
    public abstract class AuditableBaseEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Quiz Entity.

```
    public class Quiz : AuditableBaseEntity
{
    public string QuizName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Question Entity

```
    public class Question : AuditableBaseEntity
{
    public string QuestionContent { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Answer Entity

```
    public class Answer : AuditableBaseEntity
{
    public string AnswerContent { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }

}
```

And I'm trying to get the Quiz By Id and trying to reach correct questions and answers. Here is my LinQ code:

```
public async Task<GetQuizByIdViewModel> GetQuizById(int id)
    {
        return await _quizzes
             .Where(q => q.Id == id)
             .Select(q => new GetQuizByIdViewModel
             {
                 Id = q.Id,
                 QuizName = q.QuizName,
                 CategoryId = q.CategoryId,
                 OwnerId = q.CreatedBy,
                 Description = q.Description,
                 OwnerName = _applicationUsers
                 .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == q.CreatedBy).UserName,
                 Questions = _questions
                 .Select(qu => new QuestionResponseDto
                 {
                     Id = qu.Id,
                     QuestionContent = qu.QuestionContent,
                     Answers = _answers
                     .Select(a => new AnswerResponseDto
                     {
                         AnswerContent = a.AnswerContent,
                         IsCorrect = a.IsCorrect,
                     })
                     .ToList(),
                 })
                 .ToList()
             }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

As you can see I dont have QuizId Field in Question Entity. But I have it on database table. And I need to reach it in LinQ To use it in Where method to filter questions and also answers. How Can I do this?

[Also In here you can see my columns of Question table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8X2U.png)

Comment: Hello, I think you have not provided the complete code for your entities. Could you please provide more information so that we can better understand your problem and help you?

Comment: It sounds like you need something like `Questions = _questions.Where(qu => qu.QuizId == q.QuizId).Select(qu => ...)`. Your object model might already include a relationship-based collection that you can access like `Questions = q.Questions.Select(qu => ...)`. Answers for each question may be similarly filtered and/or accessed via a object model collection.

Comment: @Laaziv I added the other entities. Also upload a photo about my Question columns in  database.

Comment: Why `_questions.Select` instead of `qu.Questions.Select`? The same for answers - project from navigation properties.

Comment: `_questions.Where(qu => qu.Id = Id)`